# Upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 - one pkg is upgradeable but don't upgrade

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, updates

I have an issue with one package.

`sudo apt update`

tells me that there is 1 upgradeable package. When listing it its:

`libargon2-0/focal 0~20171227-0.2 amd64 N: There is one additional version. Please use -a switch to see it.`

Then an upgrade gives me a message which is reasonable as there is still one package to be updated.

`Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.`

How can I force this package to update when `sudo apt update` is not doing it?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the package first?  ie. a `sudo apt full-upgrade` ?   Have you checked to see if you've put a *hold* on the package (ie. `apt-mark showhold) thus upgrade cannot be performed until a user with rights removes the *hold*`?  The command `sudo apt update` does **not** upgrade packages, it only updates software lists so your system can upgrade when you decide to (via `apt upgrade` or `apt full-upgrade`; the first has some restrictions on what it can upgrade)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1498269/edit) to show the complete output of `apt policy libargon2-0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling it manually

```
sudo apt purge libargon2-0

sudo apt install libargon2-0
```

and see what happens

Comment: is that a safe solution?

Comment: the purge command will delete that pkg from scratch, will remove every single entry of config where this lib wrote since installed... perhaps there's some file that is causing that error.

Comment: its a system package and im afraid after deleting this I might not be able to install that for some strange reason....

Comment: it's, but is not installed by default on the system, another program could easily use it. I made a search, it appears when u use apt search libargon2-0 .. so u could install it no matter what.